# PrimeFaces second dialog window not opening from first dialog

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a issue trying to open a second dialog from the first dialog. The first dialog opens fine but the second dialog does not seem to open at all. I have tried with the form tag inside and outside of the dialog but get neither seems to open the dialog. On clicking the OPen dialog button from the first nothing seems to happen. I am using PrimeFaces 3.5.

Code for dialog is as below

```
<p:dialog id="dialog" header="New Submission" widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false" modal="true" closable="true">  
        <h:form id="createDialogForm">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">  
            <h:outputLabel for="projectDropDown" value="Project:" />  
            <h:selectOneMenu id="projectDropDown" value="#{newSubmissionBean.submission.project}"  required="true">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose project" noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{newSubmissionBean.projectEntities}" var="project" itemLabel="#{project.name}" itemValue="#{project}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>


            <f:facet name="footer">  
                <p:commandButton id="createButton" value="Create" update=":newSubmissionForm :createDialogForm"   
                    actionListener="#{newSubmissionBean.createSubmission}" 
                    oncomplete="handleRequest(xhr, status, args)"
                    />

                <p:commandButton id="chooseBatchButton" value="OPen dialog" update=":batchChooserForm"   
                    actionListener="#{newSubmissionBean.fetchAvailability}" />  
            </f:facet>  
        </h:panelGrid>  
          </h:form>
        </p:dialog>  






        <p:dialog id="batchDialog" header="Batch Chooser" widgetVar="bdlg" resizable="false" modal="true" closable="true">
        <h:form id="batchChooserForm"> 
            <p:fieldset legend="#{messages['label.legend.sample.available']}">  
                <p:dataTable id="availableSamples" var="sample" value="#{newSubmissionBean.availableSamples}">  
                    <p:column style="width:20px">  
                        <h:outputText id="dragIcon"  
                            styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4" />  
                        <p:draggable for="dragIcon" revert="true" />  
                    </p:column>  

                    <p:column headerText="#{messages['label.sample.batch']}">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{sample.sampleId}" />  
                    </p:column>  



                </p:dataTable>  
            </p:fieldset>  

            <p:fieldset id="selectedSamples" legend="#{messages['label.legend.sample.selected']}" style="margin-top:20px">  
                <p:outputPanel id="dropArea">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{messages['label.drop.text']}"  
                            rendered="#{empty newSubmissionBean.selectedSamples}"  
                            style="font-size:24px;" />  

                    <p:dataTable var="sample" value="#{newSubmissionBean.selectedSamples}"   
                            rendered="#{not empty newSubmissionBean.selectedSamples}">  

                        <p:column headerText="#{messages['label.sample.batch']}">  
                            <h:outputText value="#{sample.sampleId}" />  
                        </p:column>  


                        <!-- p:column style="width:32px">  
                            <p:commandButton update=":carForm:display"  
                                    oncomplete="carDialog.show()"  
                                    icon="ui-icon-search">  
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{car}"  
                                    target="#{tableBean.selectedCar}" />  
                            </p:commandButton>  
                        </p:column-->  
                    </p:dataTable>  
                </p:outputPanel>  
            </p:fieldset> 

            <p:commandButton id="confirmBatch" value="Confirm Selection" update=":newSubmissionForm :createDialogForm"   
                    actionListener="#{newSubmissionBean.confirmSelection}" 
                    oncomplete="handleRequest(xhr, status, args)"/> 

            <p:droppable for="selectedSamples" tolerance="touch" activeStyleClass="ui-state-highlight" datasource="availableSamples" onDrop="handleDrop">  
                <p:ajax listener="#{newSubmissionBean.onSampleDrop}" update="dropArea availableSamples" />  
            </p:droppable> 
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
```

the javascript function for on complete is

```
    <script type="text/javascript">  
    function handleRequest(xhr, status, args) {  
        if(args.validationFailed) {  
            dlg.show();

        }   
        else {  
            dlg.hide(); 

        }  
    }  
</script>
```

And the code in the action listener where I try to open the second dialog. This method does get called as I have break pointed on it.

```
public void fetchAvailability(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("batchDialog.show()");
}
```

Can anyone advise what I have done wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're using the id of the dialog in your javascript, you need to use the widgetVar as such:

```
public void fetchAvailability(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("bdlg.show()");
}
```

For future debuggning, try executing the javascript in your web browser console. In this case it should say "batchDialog is not defined" or something similar, giving you a hint.

Comment: I changed the call to open the dialog as shown above however it still does not open the second dialog and just shows the first. Before I moved the call to the managed bean I used to have oncomplete="bdlg.show()" as a attribute of the command button

Comment: What happens if you type bdlg.show(); in the javascript console? You need to isolate the issue to see if the problem is your action listener, or the javascript executed by it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured out what the issue was just in case anybody has the same thing. The Primefaces showcase example code has not defined the handledrop javascript function thus object undefined error is thrown. So I added the following to my code and now my pop up shows up.

```
function handleDrop(event, ui) {
        var selectedSample = ui.draggable;          
        selectedSample.fadeOut('fast');
    }
```

Thanks